# Java Calculation of variable

Tags: java, class, salesforce, apex

I try to make a calculation of two values.
But I didn't get a value. 
I want to make a addition of the value Altersstruktur_u18 and Altersstruktur_1822. In the future I need also the same but for division.

Could you help me please.

```
public class testfor3_c {

private Id accId {get; set;}
public testfor3_c(ApexPages.StandardController stdcontroller) { 
    accId = stdcontroller.getRecord().Id;

    Altersstruktur_u18 = 0;    
    Altersstruktur_1822 = 0;  

    getEZRen();   
}

public Integer Altersstruktur_u18 {get; set;} // variable for people < 18
public Integer Altersstruktur_1822 {get; set;} // variable for people >= 18 AND <= 22
public Integer Sum_u18_1822 {get; set;}

}

public void getEZRen() {

List<Einzelrisiko__c> EZRList = [SELECT Alter__c, Jahresbeitrag__c, Alter_bei_Vertragsbeginn__c FROM Einzelrisiko__c WHERE Abgangsdatum__c = Null AND Unternehmens_Id_Long__c = :accId]; // create List EZRList with the information Alter__c of all people

FOR (Einzelrisiko__c EZR : EZRList) {  // Loop thru all people

    IF(EZR.Alter__c < 18) { Altersstruktur_u18++; } // if Alter__c < 18 variable Altersstruktur_u18 increase
    IF(EZR.Alter__c >= 18 && EZR.Alter__c <= 22) { Altersstruktur_1822++; } // if Alter__c >= 18 AND <= 22 variable Altersstruktur_1822 increase

} 

Integer Sum_u18_1822 = (Altersstruktur_u18 + Altersstruktur_1822);

}

}
```

Thanks in advance,
pex

Comment: The addition is ok. getEZRen() shouldn't be: public Integer and return Sum_u18_1822 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it. I deleted the type integer at the last syntax

```
Sum_u18_1822 = (Altersstruktur_u18 + Altersstruktur_1822);
```